# Keyword 'const' on functions imply a full read-only of the object fields?

Tags: c++, constants

Having the following object

```
class Parser
{

public:
    Parser(ComponentFactory * const factory): _factory(factory) {};
    ~Parser() = default;

    void parse() const {
       _factory->setFoo("foo");
    }

private:
    Factory * _factory;
};
```

My function `parse()` is specified as `const`. That's to say the function shouldn't modify the current object state and performs only read-only logics.

However, does the modification of the factory object imply a change of my current object's state? In other therms, is this even compilable?
I would like to understand why if yes, since I can't find any related subject on the net..

EDIT:

Since none can understand this, let me try to explain it better. In simple words, is the above code supposed to compile?

Comment: It depends how `Factory` is defined...

Comment: `_factory` is `const`, what `_factory` points to is not.

Comment: factory is a simple object that holds values

Comment: @nwp I already know this, I just wanna know the if the keyword const on the function restrict me to don't write on any sub object

Comment: Define "sub object". If you consider the object pointed to by `_factory` a "sub object" then the answer is no.

Comment: The answers to the questions in the last paragraph are: "No" and "Yes". I am not sure what else you are hoping to get out of your post.

Comment: none of you read the topic, I already specified all of this

Comment: Constness is not transitive through pointers.

Comment: You dont reply to my question

Comment: Are you asking if making `parse` `const` is correct because it changes what `_factory` points to?

Comment: @Romain - I'm certain that the people *did* read your  topic. If they aren't directly replying to your question, then perhaps that question isn't clear to them. Can you rephrase or emphasize your precise question?

Comment: I would have written the field _factory without const, it confused all of you. I already know I can write on the pointed object even with the pointer as const

Comment: edited the topic

Comment: Unless you made some silly mistake somewhere this is supposed to compile. But you knew that already so I don't understand why you added that edit.

Comment: Did not know, i cant compile any code from where I am. I wasn't sure it compile, and even if yes, I would like to get some explainations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, does the modification of the factory object imply a change of my current object's state?

No

> In other therms, is this even compilable?

Yes.

> I would like to understand why if yes, since I can't find any related subject on the net..

Say you have

```
struct Foo
{
   int* ptr;
   Foo() : ptr(new int(0)) {}

   // It is valid since it does not change the state of Foo.
   // It does not change where ptr points to. It just changes
   // the value of what ptr points to.
   void set(int value) const { *ptr = value; }
};
```

The compiler gives you the basic `const` characteristics.  Higher level `const`-ness needs to be implemented by classes themselves.

In the case of `Foo`, if changing the value of what `ptr` to is deemed to change the state of `Foo` by the creator of `Foo`, then you'll have to remove `const` qualifier from the member function.

Answer (score 0):

Marking a function as `const` means that you can't:

- change any of the values of `this`'s ivars
- call a non-`const` function on `this` or any of its ivars

E.g. it would treat `int foo;` as `const int foo;`

These properties aren't transitive to pointers. `Factory *_factory;` doesn't become `const Factory *_factory;`, it becomes `Factory *const _factory;`, which is what you already have.

Imagine if you were using a smart pointer instead, would you expect the compiler to know that it should convert `std::shared_ptr<Factory> _factory;` into `std::shared_ptr<const Factory> _factory;`? All it would do is treat it as `const std::shared_ptr<Factory> _factory;`

Comment: What is an ivars?